# Can't seem to get the products showing up on the home page. I keep getting "There are no products matching the selection."

Tags: configuration, catalog

http://saltyclothing.com/index.php/

I am new to Magento and believe my problem is that we may have deleted or renamed the default or root category. I am basically looking for help in finding how to recreate my root category to the current name so that all my products will show up.

They have all been brought in and made visible and put into their sub categories. I have spent alot of time putting all my products into the catalog with their info and photos and am being very careful not to destroy what I have already built.

I appreciate any advise. Thank you.

Comment: "we may have deleted" - You should first of all check if you have deleted or renamed the default or root category or not. If you're unsure, please ask the more concrete question, e.g. how to find that out. For a Q&A site like *Magento beta* it makes not much sense to ask about what may be but to ask *your* concrete question. Another useful thing is to search for the error message to check for related Q&A, e.g. http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/1423/4115, http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/6565/4115, ... - those often contain useful infos especially if you're new. Get more than just two.

Comment: Hello thank you for your response. So far I have created a new root category for the store and set that in system manage stores. I see all of my categories come up on the front end in the side bar but no products. The products are all in the categories they need to be and each product is set to visible and enabled. Very confusing at this point . This is my url http://saltyclothing.com/

Comment: Do the products have stock?

Comment: Yes sir. my products have been synced over into magento from apparel magic  with all info including stock.

Comment: And after import, did you re-index all indexes of your store? If not, try that and check if the products appear after re-indexing has finished.